# NIO support in Jersey

Tags: tomcat, jersey, nio

Does latest version of jersey take advantage of NIO?

We are using tomcat 6.0.x version in production with J2SE 6.x

--
Regards,
Praveen Ramachandra

Answer (score 0):

If you use Grizzly as the embedded web server - that DOES use NIO.